# Model is null in view on foreach

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have added a list to my view model but when I access it in a foreach loop in the view it throws:

```
  NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCore.Views_MyActivationCampaign_Campaign.ExecuteAsync() in Campaign.cshtml
+ foreach(var dp in Model.DpRestrictedList)
```

This is the list I have added:

```
 public List<DpRestricted> DpRestrictedList { get; set; } = new List<DpRestricted>()
        {
            new DpRestricted(){DpId = 1, Name = "Post Restricted" },
            new DpRestricted(){DpId = 2, Name = "Unrestricted" },
            new DpRestricted(){DpId = 3, Name = "Customer Restricted" }
        };

    }

    public class DpRestricted
    {
        public int DpId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and I am trying to loop over it like this:

```
<div class="row">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Delivery Methods</legend>
                        <div id="radio">
                            @*<input type="radio" id="new-method">
                            <label for="new-method">New Method</label>

                            <input type="radio" id="dm-101" checked="checked">
                            <label for="dm-101">DM_101</label>

                            <input type="radio" id="delivery-method-2">
                            <label for="delivery-method-2">Delivery Method 2</label>*@
                            @{ 
                                foreach(var dp in Model.DpRestrictedList)
                                {
                                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.DeliveryPointRestrictionId, dp);
                                }
                            }
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
```

Using statement and example:

```
@model WorkstreamX.Web.Core.ViewModels.ActivationCampaignViewModel
...
 <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="headline">Campaign</label>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CampaignName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CampaignName)
                </div>
```

The above is the using statement in the view and an example of how it is already being used elsewhere in it. When I check it is not just the list that is null but the Model in the loop statement is also null. Is it a case of me needing to new up the view model in the controller at this point? That is what I am about to try I just wanted to state this question and maybe find out why this is happening. Any advice here greatly appreciated.

[edit] How I fixed this issue:

I added an argument to my view:
before `return View();`
after `return View(new ActivationCampaignViewModel());`

I still don't quite understand the why of this as I appeared to have a model before. I am assuming that because I didn't call the constructor the list wasn't constructed and made it all fall over.

Comment: Yeah sorry I fired the question in too early and all I needed to get rid of the exception was to new the view model in the controller and pass it in. Why is this the case as I seem to have had a model object before. Is it just because of the default set to the list that then required the newing up of the object?

Comment: The difference is that before you were only using *lambda expressions* based on the model, rather than an instance of the model, which would've always been `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I fixed this issue:

I added an argument to my view: 
before `return View();` 
after `return View(new ActivationCampaignViewModel());`

I still don't quite understand the why of this as I appeared to have a model before. I am assuming that because I didn't call the constructor the list wasn't constructed and made it all fall over.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like the below one.

```
Public ActionResult GetEmployee()   
{   
var employee = GetEmployee();    
return View(employee);    
}  

@model IEnumerable<Appname.ViewModel.Employee>    

@{   
foreach(var data in Model)    {}    
}
```

Comment: Please, add context to your answer. Code itself is not sufficient. Explain why you think that should work.